# What is the best practice for substituting config parameters during testing?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I'm testing a method that uses a public key to encrypt a social security number before it is saved to a database. It looks like this:

```
public function setSsnAttribute($value)
{
    // Load the public key
    $public = file_get_contents(Config::get('certificates.public'));

    // Attempt to encrypt the social security number using the public key
    if (!openssl_public_encrypt($value, $crypted, $public))
    {
        throw new Exception('Could not encrypt data. Nothing was stored.');
    }

    // The value of $crypted returned by openssl_public_encrypt contains
    // binary characters. Rather than storing the data in a BLOB, I'm
    // electing to use base64 encoding to convert it to a string that is
    // suitable for storage in the database.
    $crypted = base64_encode($crypted);

    $this->attributes['ssn'] = $crypted;
}
```

The issue is with the `Config::get('certificates.public')` call. I want to make sure that the appropriate exception is thrown if the encryption step fails. The value from `Config::get('certificates.public')` returns the path to the public certificate that is defined in a config file. My thinking is that the simplest way to test the exception would be to provide a bad path for the public certificate.

I could define an additional parameter in my config file. I'm thinking something along the lines of `certificates.test.public.bad` would return `/dev/null` or something like that.

What is the best practice for specifying alternate config parameters during unit testing? Loading the path to the certificate within the `setSsnAttribute` method seems suspect to me. Is there a more testing-friendly way to load config parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back to the Laravel documentation, I realized that I can override any config parameters I need to by simply calling `Config::set()` on the parameter from within the unit test. For example:

```
/**
 * @expectedException Exception
 */
public function testSsnDecryptionFailureThrowsException()
{
    // Replace the private certificate with
    Config::set('certificates.private', '/dev/null');

    $application = FactoryMuff::create('Lease317\RentalApplication');

    // I must access the attribute in order to trigger the decryption
    $application->ssn;
}
```

This works as expected and now I have 100% code coverage on the model.